# Show indicators while programmatically scrolling UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop

I am writing a framework which simplifies common (but sometimes tricky) drag and drop tasks in iOS. As part of this framework, when the user drags (and briefly holds) an object near the edge of a scrollView, it will scroll the scrollView programmatically in the direction of the edge.

I am able to scroll just fine using -setContentOffset:animated:(passing NO to animated) and an NSTimer, but the scroll indicators do not show up.  This leads to a confusing user experience (it can be hard to tell it is scrolling if the background is plain/untextured).

I have tried calling -flashScrollIndicators from my NSTimer callback (as the contentOffset is set), but for some reason the indicators wait until the scrolling has completed before flashing.

The effect I want is for the indicators to appear while the scrolling is happening and then disappear once it has stopped. Basically, I want the same effect as when the user scrolls the scrollView with their finger to be triggered for my programatic scrolling caused by the drag.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I seem to be having trouble too, so i am withdrawing my answer.

Comment: Can you please post code which you have did..so i can lookout and try to give you solution

Answer (score -2):

I Think you can do by some animation programming.